# Android Camera Activity restarts the app on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I've been working with an app that has a camera activity that takes  pictures. The normal behavior is to take a picture, send it as an intent and then close this activity, but on Samsung devices this just closes an restarts the app. I tested it on emulators and an Asus tablet and it worked fine. I also tested it on multiple OS versions but I haven't seen a difference. The Samsung devices with the problem are: S4, S2, and Note.

Here is the camera activity:

```
package app.xqute.com.xqute.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import app.xqute.com.xqute.R;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import timber.log.Timber;

/**
* Created by mbarisa on 5/21/15.
*/
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
@InjectView(R.id.cameraPreview)
FrameLayout mCameraPreview;
@InjectView(R.id.btnCapture)
ImageButton mBtnCapture;

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private int midScreenHeight, midScreenWidth;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create the Camera preview view
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    mCameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    midScreenHeight = display.getHeight() / 2;
    midScreenWidth = display.getWidth() / 2;

    // TODO: remove this and enable faceDetectionListener
    mBtnCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btnCapture)
void capture() {
//        mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
    mCamera.takePicture(() -> {
    }, null, mPicture);
}

final Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = (data, camera) -> {
    System.out.println("data = " + data.length);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("data", data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
};

final Camera.FaceDetectionListener faceDetectionListener = (faces, camera) -> {
    try {
        Timber.v("face: " + faces[0].rect.centerX() + " | " + faces[0].rect.centerY());
        int posX = midScreenWidth - faces[0].rect.centerX();
        int posY = midScreenHeight + faces[0].rect.centerY();

        mBtnCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        System.out.println("posY = " + posY);
        System.out.println("posX = " + posX);

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        mBtnCapture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    mPreview.stopPreview();
}

/**
 * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
 * <p>
 * Returns null if camera is unavailable
 */
private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist). Do nothing.
    }
    return c;
}

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                //  mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);

                // mCamera.startFaceDetection();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }
    private void stopPreview() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // Stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            // Tried to stop a non-existent preview. Do nothing.
        }

        try {
            // Set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        // Start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - h) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - h);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

}

Any ideas why this is happening? Or maybe a way to fix or avoid this?

Comment: At what point does the App restart - before or after the picture has been taken? Could the App appear to restart due to screen being rotated?

Comment: This happens after I take the picture. Screen rotation doesn't do anything since the activity is locked to portrait view.

Comment: I was facing this issue too, specifically in samsung devices. Somehow I resolved it, here is my answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36640559/3819836

Comment: adelphus I am seeing the same issue, but it only happens when I am taking a photo in landscape. I'm interested why you queried whether the phone was in landscape. Do you have further information?